# how to read mails from gmail with imap by using java socket

Tags: java, email, sockets, gmail, imap

I'm kinda interested in with java sockets in these days and i want to read my mails from gmail with using java socket. is it possible?

```
Socket s;
s = new Socket("imap.gmail.com", 993);
InputStream in;
in = s.getInputStream();
BufferedReader sin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
String line;
output.println("a001 LOGIN my-e-mail my-pass");
output.flush();
while ((line = sin.readLine()) != null)
System.out.println(line);
s.close();
```

what should i do after connecting to socket?

thanks in advance. (notice: i dont want to use java mail api, things get really easy with it, i'm just choosing this way to get familiar what's going on behind the scene)

edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a socket you implement the IMAP protocol on it.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501

Comment: ok i guess i should use this command
Example:    C: a001 LOGIN SMITH SESAME
               S: a001 OK LOGIN completed
 first and login to my account i do it by using a outputstreamwriter but server doesn't give me a response

Comment: A call to flush() to push the output down the socket might be called for.

Comment: And Ryan Stewart's answer is also apposite. Best to run your own toy imap server for this.

Comment: i solved the problem , sslsocket should be used to communicate with gmail. flush() is necessary. after flush just read the inputstream.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel like getting familiar with IMAP at GMail, you're going to have to put SSL/TLS on top of it. All GMail traffic is encrypted.

Answer (score -1):

+1 for the question.

EDIT: Yes, it is possible to speak to IMAP server using java sockets and in some cases it might be advisable to do so rather than using java mail library.

Using javamail is the easy way out. It is also appears to be the obvious solution but, there are cases when you do not want to go that route.

Javamail is highly unsuiatble for scaled out deployments with a large number of concurrent users that need to be kept notified on near real time basis.

Say, you want to service more than 1000 users per jvm and want to keep the overhead of creating imap connections low then, you will resort to implementing sockets yourself and write IMAP commands in the socket itself. Needless to say, other benefits include near instantaneous  delivery of a new email to your user i.e if you are using AJAX.

Near instantaneous email is one of the few things left to like about Blackberry. Given RIMs  scale, I don't think they would be using Javamail on top of IMAP to push out emails. That would be highly non-performant.

Comment: This is an answer to what question?

Comment: Answer == Write IMAP commands in the socket itself. Full description of how to do this is beyond the scope of this popularity contest.

Comment: My comment was in the hope that you would revise your answer to be an answer rather than a tangent. I've already voted to close the question as it isn't well written and isn't likely to get answered appropriately (as evidenced here).

Comment: Sorry, if it wasn't obvious. Edited.